# Gradle child modules evaluation dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-cloud

I have a bunch of projects whose configuration should be based on a template (only name changes, different dependencies). To do that I defined a parent project called "server" that holds that common configuration part in *subprojects* section.

```
group 'com.kbhit.orangebox.server'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE"
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:3.0.1'
    }
}

import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.container.DockerCreateContainer
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.container.DockerStartContainer
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.container.DockerStopContainer
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.DockerBuildImage
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.Dockerfile


ext.defineArtifact = { Map artifact ->

    ext {
        projectName = "$artifact.name"
        projectVersion = '1.0.0'
        artifactName = "$artifact.name-artifact.version.jar"
        dockerBuildDir = "$buildDir/docker/"
    }

    springBoot {
        executable = true
    }

    docker {
        url = 'http://192.168.99.101:2376'
        certPath = file(System.getProperty('docker.cert.path') ?: "${System.getProperty('user.home')}/.docker/machine/machines/default")
    }

    jar {
        baseName = projectName
        version = projectVersion
    }

    task createDockerfile(type: Dockerfile) {
        destFile = file("$buildDir/docker/Dockerfile")
        from 'java:8u91'
        exposePort 8080
        copyFile "$buildDir/docker/app.jar", '/app/app.jar'
        workingDir '/app'
        defaultCommand 'java', '-jar', 'app.jar'
    }

    task buildImage(type: DockerBuildImage, group: 'docker') {
        dependsOn 'bootRepackage', 'createDockerfile'
        inputDir = file("$buildDir/docker")

        doFirst {
            copy {
                from "$buildDir/libs"
                into dockerBuildDir
                include artifactName
                rename artifactName, 'app.jar'
            }
        }
    }

    task createContainer(type: DockerCreateContainer, group: 'docker') {
        dependsOn buildImage
        targetImageId { buildImage.getImageId() }
        containerName projectName
    }

    task startContainer(type: DockerStartContainer, group: 'docker') {
        dependsOn createContainer
        targetContainerId { createContainer.getContainerId() }
    }

    task stopContainer(type: DockerStopContainer, group: 'docker') {
        targetContainerId { createContainer.getContainerId() }
    }

}

subprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
    apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        maven {
            url('http://localhost:10001/content/groups/public/')
        }
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Brixton.RELEASE'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
            exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
        }
        compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.5.0'
        compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.5.0'
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
        testCompile("junit:junit")
        testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '2.3'
    }

}


afterEvaluate {
    task startServer() {
        dependsOn subprojects.startContainer
    }
}
```

Here's the configuration of one of the modules:

```
defineArtifact(name: 'orb-api-gateway', version: '1.0.0')

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zuul'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
    testCompile group: 'com.jayway.restassured', name: 'rest-assured', version: '2.9.0'
}
```

The problem is that:

1. Child projects need to "inject" their properties "up" before those are requested in task definitions, eg. buildImage task - I'd use `$dockerBuildDir` variable which should be defined in defineArtifact method based on the arguments provided by the child module.
2. Parent module must have access to tasks created for child modules. See *startServer* task at the bottom.

Of course this won't work as at the time no task are created. If I were to fix this I would have to make *server* project evaluate after it's children but then I would not be able to define *defineArtifact* method before children request it. How to solve this problem?

Comment: This actually looks like a perfect excuse to make your own plugin.